# How to show back button at root with React Native Router?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am using [React Native Router](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) and want to have a back button on the component at the root of the navigation and override its action.

Is it possible to enable the back button without writing my own with `renderBackButton`? I'd rather use the one provided with the library to ensure consistency between other screens and avoid writing a new component.

I tried with `hideBackImage={false}`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Since you're at the root of your application, you only have one scene in your stack.

But why do you want a back button on your first application screen? It makes no sense...

However, it's pretty easy to render a back button with a custom action. For example :

```
<Scene key='root'
    ...    
    renderLeftButton={this.renderCustomButton()}
    ...
/>
```

With

```
renderCustomButton() {
  return () => (
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <Icon name="back" size={30} color="#900" />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

Then you just add your action or whatever you want to do with the onLeft prop

```
<Scene key='root'
    ...    
    renderLeftButton={this.renderCustomButton()}
    onLeft={**YOUR ACTION**}
    ...
/>
```

You can also add it on the TouchableOpacity onPress prop.

I usually use react-native-vector-icons for my custom navbar icons https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons

Comment: I originally wanted to do this to dismiss a search bar (similar to the Google Maps Android app). Pushing a new page on the stack made the transition look very buggy, so as a workaround, the search page was in the same component as the root of nav. I ended up creating the back button with the search bar view instead of in the nav bar. Thanks for your answer though, it is a totally valid way of doing it!